# automatically update the function calls by renaming the module aliases

Tags: python, import, module, package

I'm currently updating the structure of a (old and poorly designed) personal package: I'm creating some new modules, and move some functions from old modules to new ones. 
Then, the complete structure of my previous work, and more specifically calls of the functions both in this package and my scripts are modified.

Thus, I’m wondering if there is an existing tool which can automatically update the function calls by renaming the module aliases ?

for instance I had before:

```
import my_old_module as mom 
mom.my_function
```

and I moved `my_function` to a new module `my_new_module`, I plan to import that way

```
import my_new_module as mnm
```

So is there a way to check and modify automatically the new dependencies ? to get `mnm.my_function`
(for of course, dozen of modules and hundred of functions)

Answer (score 0):

[Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/refactoring-source-code.html) implements many tools associated with refactoring code.

For instance you can rename modules by right clicking on the file in the directory view and clicking on rename from the refactor category. This will open a dialog allowing you to rename the module. When you click on "Refactor" It will show you all the places it plans to change the references, allowing you to verify that everything will be updated correctly.